# Find a matrix of the given operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the operator

()=2″(x) - x′(1) + x(1)

Find a matrix of the operator on a basis of P2. Find its eigenvalues, and check if it is diagonalizable.

I know how to find eigenvalues and check if they are diagonalizable, but I don't know how to find a matrix of the operator.

Comment: The steps are: 1. Pick an ordered basis (any will do), 2. Transform each vector in this basis, 3. Write these transformed vectors as coordinate column vectors in terms of the original basis, and 4. Put these column vectors as columns in a matrix (in order).

Comment: Do you know how the matrix of a linear map is defined? Because you say that you know how to diagonalise the given operator, but that requires you know the definition of a matrix of a linear map.